# OSX app built with python quits immediately if app bundle is executed from finder but runs fine from command line

Tags: macos, pyqt, pyqt4, pyinstaller, py2app

So I have this pyqt project and I want to build a osx.app dmg using pyinstaller

pyinstaller created the output in

```
dist/MyApplication.app
```

I can run it directly from terminal

```
cd dist
./MyApplication.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApplication
```

However, if I try to run the app bundle directly either with

```
open -a MyApplication.app
```

or

```
open .
# double click on MyApplication.app folder (appears just as MyApplication from finder)
```

It starts and then quits immediately

Now if I navigate to

```
$ cd ./Contents/MacOS/
```

and open a finder

```
$ open .
#then double click on MyApplication
```

it runs fine, but with a terminal windows opened in the background

```
Last login: Fri Mar 14 18:01:13 on ttys005
MyApplication/dist/MyApplication.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApplication ; exit;
MyApplication/dist/MyApplication.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApplication ; exit;
```

I use similar steps to build a windows exe without any issues (although there is no MyApplication.app concept in windows)

How do I diagnose this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I followed this [py2app tutorial](https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/tutorial.html) to see if it works better than pyinstaller, with this code

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    print "Hello"
```

and got similar results

i.e. app closes when I do

```
open -a HelloTest.app
```

while it runs fine with

```
./HelloTest.app/Contents/MacOS/HelloTest
```

but then this tidbit in the tutorial explains it

```
When run normally, your application’s stdout 
and stderr output will go to the Console logs. 
To see them, open the Console application:

$ open -a Console
```

After examining the console logs, it seems like if I run

```
open -a MyApplication.app
```

the app runs in a sandbox and if you open any file to write without specifying absolute
 path it will fail to create the file

if I run

```
./MyApplication.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApplication
```

directly the app can create files in the current directory

So I have to go back and specify the full path while creating files, instead of just assuming it will create in the working directory.

Comment: I'm having this issue too. I don't think open -a is a valid solution (your app users will have to do it that way too).

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. I know this post is kind of old, but if possible, can you elaborate just a bit on how you solved this? I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

When you build an OSX app bundle with pyinstaller, it will crash if you use relative paths and try to write files in the working directory.

To write files in the working directory without using absolute paths, make your paths like this:

path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), "file")

Answer (score 0):

I had something very similar except I **could** run it with `open -a AppName` - it just crashed when run from finder.

In my case, it was an import involving `ffmpeg` which was the culprit:

```
from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_extract_subclip
```