# PyInstaller OS X app runs from command line, but not Finder window

Tags: macos, pyinstaller

I have an application bundle created with PyInstaller on OS X.  If I double click the .app bundle in Finder, the application tries to launch, then terminates.  No further information is given in the console, other than the application quit.

But if I launch the app executable from the terminal (i.e., `./Contents/MacOS/MyApplication`, it works perfectly fine.  This seems to be the same behavior experienced in this issue: [OSX app built with python quits immediately if app bundle is executed from finder but runs fine from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418418/osx-app-built-with-python-quits-immediately-if-app-bundle-is-executed-from-finde), but the marked solution there isn't particularly helpful.

I suspect this is indeed related to an environment or path issue.  But I'm not sure how to fix it.  Should something be specified in the `info.plist` file maybe?  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is most likely due to a bad assumption about the working directory. When you launch from the Finder, the working directory may well be `/` (depends on OS X version), which is not writeable. If your app writes to the current working directory then you should probably set the working directory to somewhere sensible at startup.

Comment: Interesting. By adding `print os.getcwd()` to my main script, I was able to see that when run from the finder, the working directory indeed is `/`, but when run from the terminal, it's `/Users/MyName/Development/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS`. I tried setting the working directory to that (i.e., `os.chdir`) just to see what would happen, but still no success. Any thoughts on where the working directory should be set to? And how it should be set? Thank you!!

Comment: So long as you set the working directory prior to any file I/O you should be OK - setting it to your home directory would probably be a good place to try first, as that's guaranteed to be writeable.

Comment: `os.chdir` to an arbitrary location (script dir) does not work. Window disappears as usual.

Comment: Hmm has anyone figured out how to debug this?  Would be great to get debug messages from an app that's opened in Finder.